# Sql Join does not show the new inserted rows in sqlite table

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, sqlite

I have IPhone application in which I am inserting data. It works fine when I fetch all the data without any condition then it works fine if given any condition like

following query then it does not show anything.

```
NSString *select =
          [NSString stringWithFormat:
               @"SELECT * from ContentMaster  As ml
                          LEFT JOIN ContentTagging As cat
                          ON cat.ContentID = ml.ContentID 
                 where cat.ContenTagText= \'%@\'" ,appDelegate.tagInput];


const char *sql = [select UTF8String];
```

then it does not show any thing using this if i use the `select * form ContentMaster` then it shows all records added.

Comment: As an aside, you should never use `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL statements. What if `tagInput` had an apostrophe in it? Your code would fail. You should. Always use `?` placeholders and then bind text values with `sqlite3_bind_text`.

Comment: Did `sqlite3_prepare_v2` return `SQLITE_OK`? If not, what did `sqlite3_errmsg` report? perhaps you can share more code as well as the `schema table_info()` for both tables. The `ContenTagText` looks suspicious. (Is it `ContentTagText`?) But without some more code, and info about the table schemas, and a few the records in the tables, it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: What is the value of `tagInput`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * from ContentMaster  
LEFT JOIN ContentTagging 
ON ContentMaster.ContentID = ContentTagging.ContentID 
WHERE ContentTagging.ContenTagText= \'%@\'"
```

Comment: Why?  What is differnt about this?